# SQL Create Trigger Before Delete vs. Foreign Key On Delete

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-delete, cascading-deletes

I have one table referencing another. As I see - there are two ways to delete cascading:

**What** is the difference between `CREATE TRIGGER BEFORE DELETE` and `FOREIGN KEY ON DELETE`? Are there any differences in performance?

I came up with this advantage of `FOREIGN KEY`: 
The cascading delete is more obvious because it's attached in the table definition.

Full question: 
I have the two tables: 
`project(id, ...) <- works_on(id, project_id, ...)`

What are the differences in

```sql
CREATE TABLE works_on (
  ...
  FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES project ON DELETE CASCADE
  ...
);
```

and

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_delete_cascading
  BEFORE DELETE ON project
  DELETE works_on
    WHERE project_id = id;
```

Comment: They are very similar.  I would advise you to always go with the cascading delete (if that is what you want), so the database takes care of relational integrity.  It also has the advantage of validating the value in the column.

Comment: In my case your comment and Serge's accepted answer solve this mystery. Sagar Gangwal also advised to use "Foreign Key" concerning more consistency: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42114888/1700776

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `FOREIGN KEY` will restrict values that can be stored in the `project_id` column of the `works_on` table. You will not be able to set a value that does not exist in the `project` table.

A `TRIGGER` does not restrict the range of values that can be stored.

Answer (score 3):

If wrote trigger BEFORE delete,will **DELETE** record from **CHILD TABLE** and due to some Server error or Other constraint if record is unable to delete from **MAIN TABLE(PARENT)** then it makes redundant data.
So whenever you required delete plus more action like maintaining LOG table then only you have to go with Trigger.Otherwise `ON DELETE CASCADE` is great to work.
Hope this will helps you.